# Howto redirect all SSDP packets to a specific interface via iproute2?

Tags: iproute2, upnp, networking

I have a faulty app which is sending SSDP packets on the wrong interface. I made the dev aware of the problem and it will be fixed in the new release but in the mean time I was hoping I could use iproute2 as a stop-gap measure to shore up this problem.

Basically, any SSDP packets going out on interface 'eth0' I want to go out on interface 'br0' instead.

In case it matters, all of these packets are destined for 239.255.255.250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the answer is:

```
ip route add 239.255.255.250/32 dev br0
```